# FizzBuzz up to 99 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fizzbuzz

This code solves the problem of FizzBuzz. Is it possible in any way to improve it?

```
main = main' 1 where
main' n = do
    (putStrLn . choose) (show n, "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz", n)
    if n < 100 then main' (succ n) else putStrLn "End!" 
    where
        choose (n0, n3, n5, n15, n) 
            | mod n 3 == 0 && mod n 5 == 0 = n15
            | mod n 5 == 0 = n5
            | mod n 3 == 0 = n3
            | True = n0
```

Comment: Which definition of FizzBuzz are you using? Based on the [first Google result](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest) the #s are fixed at [1..100], so there shouldn't be any inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could separate your I/O from the pure code:

```
fizzBuzz :: Int -> String
fizzBuzz n | mod n 3 == 0 && mod n 5 == 0 = "FizzBuzz"
           | mod n 5 == 0                 = "Buzz"
           | mod n 3 == 0                 = "Fizz"
           | otherwise                    = show n

main = mapM print (map fizzBuzz [0..100])
```

Comment: I think `mapM (print . fizzBuzz) [0..100]` would be better.

Comment: `mapM_` would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

jaket is definitely right, the pure/impure distinction is important. My addition would be that you should avoid recomputing the modulo:

```
fizzBuzz :: Int -> String
fizzBuzz n | fizz && buzz = "FizzBuzz"
           | buzz         = "Buzz"
           | fizz         = "Fizz"
           | otherwise    = show n
           where fizz = mod n 3 == 0
                 buzz = mod n 5 == 0

sfb = map fizzBuzz [1..15]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had written something similar to [Will](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/19659/will), but the spec I read [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest) says, that FizzBuzz should always cover [1..100], so my implementation was a bit different:

```
show' :: Int -> String
show' n
    | fizz && buzz = "FizzBuzz"    
    | buzz         = "Buzz"
    | fizz         = "Fizz"
    | otherwise    = show n
    where fizz = mod n 3 == 0
          buzz = mod n 5 == 0

fizzBuzz = [show' x | x <- [1..100]]
```

Will's idea about using where to cache the mod result was a nice idea IMHO.